# Exception when calling C++ function from managed code

Tags: c#, interop

Let's imagine C++ function in DLL:

```cpp
typedef struct
{
    int number;
    void *list;
} clist_t;

extern "C" DLL_API clist_t GetItems(int a);

DLL_API clist_t GetItems(int a)
{
    static clist_t list;
    list.number = a;
    list.list = sth();
    return list;
}
```

And the C# code which calls this function:

```cs
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct CList
{
    public int number;
    public IntPtr ptr;
};

[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private delegate CList GetItemsDelegate(int a);

int func = Win32APIWrapper.GetProcAddress(m_dllHndl, "GetItems");
private GetItemsDelegate GeItemsFunc =
    (GetItmsDelegate)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer((IntPtr)func, typeof(GetItemsDelegate));
CList list = GetItemsFunc(12);  // <--- here we got exception
```

---

The last function throws exception: **"Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt."**

I noticed that removing second field in *CList* function causes exception to disappear and returned struct has correct value of *number* field.

So why the original code does not work? The alignment of structures seems to be correct. Also calling convention is properly set to *cdecl*.

Any ideas? Both types in struct are blittable, so there is no need to even marshal them (C# and dll are compiled to 32bit).

**EDIT:**

Why returning smaller struct does not throw exception? I noticed that struct smaller then 4 bytes are returned ok. On the other hand the same function but without parameters allows returning the original struct without exception.

Comment: list.list is an uninitialised void* being passed back across a marshalled interface. I'm guessing that is going to cause a problem as the marshalling will access the pointer.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't mention that this is only a snipped of code. This ptr is actually initialized correctly.

Comment: Functions that return a pointer are always suspicious.  Invoking undefined behavior with a [dangling pointer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer) is a traditional C bug.  That *will* crash your program with an AVE when the stack frames of the pinvoke marshaller overwrite the variable.

Comment: I'm sorry but I do not see the problem yet. Dll function returns the *clist_t* struct which shall be mapped onto CList by the marshaller upon return. We have two fields of matching size here. It is not relevant what value *list.number* and *list.list* have. Right?

Comment: It's to do with the fact the memory from the unmanaged DLL is in a different space to the mmanaged (C#) memory. You will need to marshall the return value to get it into the C# 'memory space'. Have a look at this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12477/Handling-Unmanaged-Memory-Pointers-in-Managed-Memo)

Comment: But I do not return any pointers between managed and unmanaged space. There is struct returned, containing just two int's (which are blittable types) so it shall be automatically mapped (copied from c++ struct to c# struct).